# Does IRLZ44N need heatsink when used as a switch

Tags: mosfet

I'm doing some modifications to my boombox and need help with **IRLZ44N**.

[image: Circuit pt1]

I don't have any good switches left but I have couple **IRLZ44N** and I've used them in car but never needed this much power, **peak power being 200W** no matter the Voltage(**11.2-16.8V**) so I have to draw **12-18A** and **I have no idea if I need a heatsink or how to calculate it**, **no need to spoon-feed me** but some help would be nice, Thanks.

Comment: Check the data-sheet for the maximum RDSon value.  I squared * R tells you the power the MOSFET will be dissipating.  Use that value to determine the size of the heatsink (if any).

Comment: @DwayneReid with fast calculations it would be about 8W of heat(correct me if Im wrong) so heatsink would be a good idea in this situation, i have some heatsinks and they have X°C/W values, what would be a good value or how do you calculate it, does 30C/W heatsink reach 240C when used in this situation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circuit, at nominal input, will exceed the absolute maximum Vgs rating of the transistor. If  you add an  8V or 9V zener diode you can prevent that.

With 5V or more drive the maximum Rds(on) is 0.028\$\Omega\$, at Tj = 25°C. So dissipation would be 18  * 18 * 0.028 = 9W. We can add perhaps 50% to that since it's going to get very, very hot, so more like 14W (See Fig. 4 in the [datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91328/sihlz44.pdf)) that's assuming you can keep the junction temperature to 100°C or less). That's a large heat sink, maybe a fan too, depending on your maximum ambient and how reliable you want it to be.

Without a heat sink it will die in seconds, if it doesn't unsolder itself first.

I would suggest finding a better MOSFET.

Comment: i don't think 0.8V would be a big deal but I do have few IRF530N and IRFZ44N, IRFZ44N has max Vgs of ±20V and max Rds(on) 17.5mΩ so using it would solve the Vgs problem and the heat output would be 5.67W, sounds better, i have few heatsinks and some have  X°C/W rating so what would be good for that or should i try to get a better MOSFET

Comment: For a few dollars you can get a through-hole MOSFET 1.5m\$\Omega\$ with 10V drive. So no heat sink or virtually none. Cheaper if you can deal with SMT.  But maybe you have a free heatsink.

Comment: I found IRLB3034 for 3Eur so I think I'm gonna go with that, max 1.7mΩ at 10V, Thanks for your help and have a good day.